# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class android.widget.ToggleButton

Tags: java, android, xml, vector, layout

I have this error in my project this error just in api 19 ( in android 4.4 )

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.noxef.notecap/com.noxef.notecap.NewEnter}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class android.widget.ToggleButton
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class android.widget.ToggleButton
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.noxef.notecap.NewEnter.onCreate(NewEnter.java:28)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 

Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/visibility_password.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0700a6
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2096)
   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_visibility.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f07008e
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector
```

What can I do - have cleaned it already

I searched for the error and found it in this XML code
just here in `android:background="@drawable/visibility_password"`:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/show"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:background="@drawable/visibility_password"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textOff=""
    android:textOn="" />
```

I'm using Vector XML in background not Image.

Comment: Could you post `visibility_password` drawable please

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_visibility" />

    <item android:state_checked="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_visibility_off" />
</selector>

Comment: Can you show a picture of hierarchy of android drawables which is found the left mst side in android studio..

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: When you expand the res folder in the left, you get many other folders.. can you send a pic of those folders from Android Studio

Comment: https://image.ibb.co/fuPL5f/Untitled.png

Comment: Okay cool.. Try using an image instead of vector drawable in visible_password.xml if it works, post your code of vector drawable too.

Comment: Yes, it works with image

Comment: <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/colorPrincipalIcon"
        android:pathData="M12,4.5C7,4.5 2.73,7.61 1,12c1.73,4.39 6,7.5 11,7.5s9.27,-3.11 11,-7.5c-1.73,-4.39 -6,-7.5 -11,-7.5zM12,17c-2.76,0 -5,-2.24 -5,-5s2.24,-5 5,-5 5,2.24 5,5 -2.24,5 -5,5zM12,9c-1.66,0 -3,1.34 -3,3s1.34,3 3,3 3,-1.34 3,-3 -1.34,-3 -3,-3z"/>
</vector>

Comment: Try out my solution below please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** Try these steps below:

First, Add this line in your `ic_visibility.xml` and `ic_visibility_off.xml`

```
<vector
    ...
    android:tintMode="multiply"
    ...>

    ......
    ......

</vector>
```

Then, Don't forget to add `build.gradle(Module:app)` or the approach will not work on old Android versions.

```
defaultConfig {
    ....
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    ....
}
```

Lastly, add this in you `activity` class, before `onCreate()`:

```
static {
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}
```

Try it. Hope it helps. Please comment if any doubts.

Comment: @AflaYoussef Happy To Help. :)

Answer (score 0):

visibility_password.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_visibility" />

    <item android:state_checked="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_visibility_off" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your this file **visibility_password.xml** must not be in the **res/drawable** directory.

Set project files as Project view. You might see some other folders like "**drawable-v24**"

Move your **visibility_password.xml** file to **res/drawable** folder.

This will resolve your issue